# How do I configure Symfony Mailer with Silverstripe?

Tags: smtp, silverstripe, swiftmailer, symfony-mailer

I am new to Silverstripe and currently doing the lessons. The version is 4.10 which has dropped support for Swiftmailer and are recommending Symfony Mailer. I have installed Symfony Mailer using Composer. There was a Symfony folder in the root directory. The installation added a sub-folder mailer in that folder.

I know I am supposed to edit the file app/_config/email.yml which looks like this:

```
# See https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/email/ for additional information about setting up email
---
Name: project-emailconfig
After:
  - '#emailconfig'
---
SilverStripe\Core\Injector\Injector:
  Swift_Transport:
    class: Swift_SendmailTransport
```

How do I edit this file to use Symfony Mailer? I would also appreciate any other alternative settings or mailer that can be used in Silverstripe 4.x, whichever will enable me send emails. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

please check the documentation to edit

https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/email/

Sometimes local servers(XAMPP) don't support to Swift_Transport.try your code on a live site.